# adicionar items dimensionais na array

Tags: php

Como posso adicionar items na array desta forma:

```
    array_push($arr, $end[0] => $end[1]);
```

nao queria que fosse adicionada uma nova array dentro da já existente e sim que fosse adicionado novos items no estilo $key => $content

pra ficar assim:

```
        [A] => B
        [C] => D
```

e nao assim:

```
array(
        array ( [A] => B ),
        array ( [C] => D )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, então é só fazer a inclusão direto no *array*:

```
$arr['A'] = 'B';
$arr['C'] = 'D';
```